# How do I translate G-Code to LLVM?

Tags: haskell, compilation, llvm, code-generation

I am following along the book [Implementing Functional Languages: A Tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/pj-lester-book/) and have basically finished a Core compiler and interpreter using the G-Machine. In the description of the chapters, it is said that G-Code can be translated into machine code, but how? The G-Code (instructions) are meant to run a state transition machine, manipulating multiple stacks and association lists. How can something like this be done in LLVM using llvm-general/llvm-general-pure packages? At the end of it all, I'd like to make this compiler output an executable file.

Here is how the state and the instructions look like:

```
type GmState = (GmOutput,   -- current output
            GmCode,     -- current instruction stream
            GmStack,    -- current stack
            GmDump,     -- a stack for WHNF reductions
            GmHeap,     -- heap of nodes
            GmGlobals,  -- global addresses in heap
            GmStats)    -- statistics

type GmOutput = [Char]

type GmCode = [Instruction]

type GmStack = [Addr]

type GmDump = [GmDumpItem]
type GmDumpItem = (GmCode, GmStack)

type GmHeap = Heap Node

type GmGlobals = ASSOC Name Addr

type GmStats = Int

data Instruction = Unwind -- unravels the spine of the evaluation tree (such as evaluating the next super combinator)
             | Pushglobal Name -- push address of global to stack
             | Pushint Int -- allocate node in heap, add address to stack
             | Push Int -- pushes the nth address in the stack to the top of the stack
             | Mkap -- takes first 2 pointers on stack and adds a new address to the top of the stack to both addresses
             | Update Int -- updates the nth address in the stack in the heap, takes the address of the top of the stack
             | Pop Int -- pops the first n addresses from the stack
             | Slide Int -- like pop, but keeps the first address on top of the stack
             | Alloc Int -- allocates n nodes in the heap and puts them on top of the stack
             | Eval -- takes current code and puts it in the dump, evaluates the top address by unwinding
             | Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Neg
             | Eq | Ne | Lt | Le | Gt | Ge 
             | Cond GmCode GmCode
             | Pack Int Int -- creates a new datatype by adding a unique name to the heap
             | Casejump [(Int, GmCode)] -- evaluates a number of cases by matching alts with datatypes in the heap
             | Split Int -- looks up first address of stack in heap, if exists then takes the list of addresses found and appends to stack
             | Print -- write to GmOutput
```

What I would essentially like to know is this: is there any LLVM data structure that can mimic the GMachine, and if there is, what is it, and is a stack machine within LLVM the right approach?

Comment: As it is the question is a bit broad. Perhaps you have some ideas for some of the instructions and only need help with a few, or...? I mean, we're not going to sit down and implement a complete compiler for you.

Comment: One option might be to look at the GHC LLVM code generator.

Comment: @DanielWagner having you guys do all the work is not my intention. This is a similar question that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870483/translating-g-machine-source-to-llvm-ir

Comment: @DanielWagner I guess to be more specific, I'd like to know how to simulate the same stack machine I have with a G Machine in LLVM, or at least something that can do the same thing. As I am not familiar with LLVM or the packages for it on Hackage, I was wondering if there is any functionality that will let me accomplish this. If there isn't, I'm looking for a point in the right direction towards a functionality that can.

Comment: One more point to add, @DanielWagner, I read in that similar link I posted that LLVM is a register machine, whereas the GMachine is a stack machine. So this is what I'm trying to clear up. The top comment on that thread could use some elaboration, because as it is it does not help me much.

Comment: Try to get hold of some the early papers from the 80s that I (Lennart Augustsson) and Thomas Johnsson wrote.  They contain some of the information.

Comment: @dfeuer, GHC is based on an STG, it's a totally different beast.